# C++ Adjacent Find: Vector iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++

I have a sorted vector that contains the following elements:

myVect = {-47, -2, -2, 19, 80, 80, 80}

I am trying to use the adjacent_find algorithm to locate and print out each range of repeated elements on a separate line, as in:

-2 -2

80 80 80

I am able to get my code to compile, and it produces the right output, except that I am getting a run-time error that says "vector iterator not dereferencable".

Here is the code:

```
vector<int>::iterator vectIt = myVect.begin();  
while (vectIt != myVect.end()) {
    vectIt = adjacent_find(vectIt, myVect.end()); 
    int currentVal = *vectIt; 
    while (*vectIt == currentVal) {
        cout << *vectIt << " ";
        if (vectIt < myVect.end()) {
            ++vectIt;
        } 
    }
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried your code (clang++ -Weverything) and I had no error. Did you have another code who can interact ? What do you use to compile ?

Comment: @aloisdg how did you run it?  (the post says it was a runtime error - not something the compile time warnings would necessarily catch)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, and running it from the command line. @aloisdg I'm not quite sure what you mean by interact? This is my first time on SE :-)

Comment: I tried compiling using g++, compiled okay, but I got a different run-time error: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: @MichaelT A [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bQZGvJ7k) to my code. No error happened when I ran the sample.

Comment: @dayFun First time here for me too. Hello ! A Segfault is a basic error. You should write somewhere you should not. Look into wiki/google for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dereferencing the `end` iterator in your second loop.

```
while (*vectIt == currentVal) {
    cout << *vectIt << " ";
    if (vectIt < myVect.end()) {
        ++vectIt;
    } 
}
```

just manually go through the case of `vectIt` being the last element in the vector (i.e. `myVect.end() - 1`, like you got when it is at the 3rd `80`):

```
if (vectIt < myVect.end()) { // will still be true
    ++vectIt; // now you set it to myVect.end()
}
```

now in the next iteration you check:

```
while (*vectIt == currentVal) // here you dereference it without checking for myVect.end()
```

you should change that condition to:

```
while (vectIt != myVect.end() && *vectIt == currentVal)
```

---

---

Note: This only works if the last elements in the vector are at least 2 equal ones. If the last element in the vector isn't equal to the one before it as in `{-47, -2, -2, 19, 80, 80, 80, 100}` then you'd hit myVect.end() only after your
    vectIt = adjacent_find(vectIt, myVect.end());

and would either `break` after it if `vectIt` is equal to `myVect.end()` or rather, like I'd suggest put the updating in the while condition.

```
vector<int>::iterator vectIt = myVect.begin();  
while ( ( vectIt = adjacent_find(vectIt, myVect.end()) ) != myVect.end()) {
    int currentVal = *vectIt; 
    while (vectIt != myVect.end() && *vectIt == currentVal) {
        cout << *vectIt << " ";
        if (vectIt < myVect.end()) {
            ++vectIt;
        } 
    }
    cout << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Gah, thank you so much! I had added the second check on the second while loop in an earlier attempt, but without changing the initial while loop to end() - 1, I was still getting the error.  I really appreciate it!